# How do I mock PolicyResult to contain a value for FinalException?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, polly

I have created an abstract class that implements Polly that I want to write unit tests for.
In one of my tests I want to test how my method handles certain values of `PolicyResult.FinalException`.
Because the returned `PolicyResult` is null I get a `NullReferenceException` when evaluating `result.FinalException`
How do I mock the returned result?

What I have so far:

```
public class AbstractRestClientTest
{
    private AbstractRestClient _sut;

    private Mock<IRestRequestFactory> _requestFactoryMock;

    private Mock<IRestClientFactory> _restClientfactoryMock;
    private Mock<IPollyPolicyFactory> _policyFactoryMock;
    private Mock<IAsyncPolicy> _policyMock;

    private const string DUMMY_URL = "http://dosomething.com/getmesomething";

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _requestFactoryMock = new Mock<IRestRequestFactory>();
        
        _restClientfactoryMock = new Mock<IRestClientFactory>();
        _policyFactoryMock = new Mock<IPollyPolicyFactory>();
        var settings = new MockSettings();

        _policyMock = new Mock<IAsyncPolicy>();
        _policyFactoryMock.Setup(mock => 
            mock.CreateAsyncResiliencePolicy(settings))
            .Returns(_policyMock.Object);

        _sut = new MockRestClient(settings, _restClientfactoryMock.Object, 
            _policyFactoryMock.Object,
            _requestFactoryMock.Object);
    }
}

public class MockRestClient : AbstractRestClient
{
    public MockRestClient(RestSettings settings, IRestClientFactory restClientFactory, IPollyPolicyFactory pollyPolicyFactory,
        IRestRequestFactory requestFactory) : base(settings, restClientFactory, pollyPolicyFactory, requestFactory) {
    }
}

public class MockSettings : RestSettings
{
    public override string Naam => "TestSettings";
}
```

------------------ EDIT 1 --------------------------------

With Nkosi's comment I got a little bit further but still PolicyResult returned by `_policy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync` is `null`. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong in the way that I mock that method.
I changed my test to the following but still it returns `null``:

```
[Test]
public async Task HandleRequest_IfFinalExceptionNotNull_ThenThrowsException()
{
    var mockResult = new Mock<IRestResponse<int>>();
    PolicyResult<IRestResponse<int>> result = PolicyResult<IRestResponse<int>>.Failure(mockResult.Object, new Context());

    //Is the following mock correctly setup?
    _policyMock.Setup(mock => mock.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(It.IsAny<Func<Task<IRestResponse<int>>>>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(result);

    var url = new Url(DUMMY_URL);
    Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => _sut.GetResult<int>(url));
}
```

I evaluated the parameters needed for `ExecuteAndCapture` and changed my setup for this method accordingly, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was mocking the wrong version of `ExecuteAndCaptureAsync`, I needed to mock the method with the following signature:

```
`Task<PolicyResult> ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(Func<CancellationToken, Task> action, CancellationToken cancellationToken);`
```

So after I changes my `SetUp` accordingly the test succeeded:

```
[Test]
public async Task HandleRequest_IfFinalExceptionNotNull_ThenThrowsException()
{
    var mockResult = new Mock<IRestResponse<int>>();
    PolicyResult<IRestResponse<int>> result = PolicyResult<IRestResponse<int>>.Failure(mockResult.Object, new Context());

    _policyMock.Setup(mock => mock.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(
        It.IsAny<Func<CancellationToken, Task<IRestResponse<int>>>>(), 
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(result);

    var url = new Url(DUMMY_URL);
    Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => _sut.GetResultaat(url, new CancellationToken()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the publicly available [source code](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/src/Polly/PolicyResult.cs) on GitHub, there really is no need to mock  that class. While it does have an internal constructor, static factory methods exist that should allow for the creation of your desired instance

For example

```
Context context = //...created as needed

PolicyResult<TestResponse> result = PolicyResult<TestResponse>.Failure(..., context);
```

Choose the right combination to satisfy the expected result in your test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I changed my code accordingly but somehow the mocked method still returns `null` for `PolicyResult`.